# Pvalue adjustment (Rcode to adjust all tests together)

Tags: r

I was wondering how I can adjust the P-value for all comparisons together. I want to run FDR for these two columns p-value1 and p-value2 together (So I will have 6 tests) and bring the results into a new column (Adjustment_Pvalues).

Something like:

```
p.adjust (c(p-value1,p-value2), method = "fdr")

Trait p-value1 p-value2    Adjustment_Pvalues
1     0.5       0.01 
2     NA         NA
3     0.2       0.45 
4     0.2       0.02
```

Comment: I'm curious. `p.adjust(c(0.5, 0.01), method = "fdr")` (e.g. applying `p.adjust` to the first row) returns a vector of length 2 (0.5, 0.02); how do you want to fit that into a single results column ... ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly (i.e. you want all of them adjusted together), you'll want to use `pivot_longer` and `pivot_wider`:

```
require(tidyverse)

df.test.long <- tibble(
  Trait = 1:4, 
  p_value1 = c(0.5, NA, 0.2, 0.2), 
  p_value2 = c(0.01, NA, 0.45, 0.02)
) %>% 
  pivot_longer(cols = -Trait, names_to = "pvalue_column", values_to = "pvalue")

df.test.long$adjusted <- p.adjust(df.test.long$pvalue, method = "fdr")

df.test.final <- df.test.long %>% pivot_wider(names_from = "pvalue_column", values_from = c(pvalue, adjusted))

# output
# A tibble: 4 × 5
  Trait pvalue_p_value1 pvalue_p_value2 adjusted_p_value1 adjusted_p_value2
  <int>           <dbl>           <dbl>             <dbl>             <dbl>
1     1             0.5            0.01               0.5              0.06
2     2            NA             NA                 NA               NA   
3     3             0.2            0.45               0.3              0.5 
4     4             0.2            0.02               0.3              0.06
```